# How to link an unreferenced variable in a separate cpp file in a static lib?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

here is a class definition like below in "init.**cpp**":

```
//-------------------init.cpp-----------------
// ...
class CNetInit {
public:
CNetInit(){::WSAStartup();}
~CNetInit() {...}
};

static CNetInit s_initor;
// ...
//---------------------------------------------
```

I just added this cpp into a **static library** , and reference this lib to my project, but CNetInit's constructor can never be executed because no there is no reference to this cpp. How can I make it work without adding some useless reference to this cpp just for importing this unit?

comment: infact this is just a sample, my code will be compiled in xcode and gcc,  is there any standard or non-standard way(like compiler options) to do this?

Comment: You need to declare this in a header file and include said header file. The definition can remain in the source file.

Comment: I don't want to reference any thing about them in any other units , I just want these code reference outside code , to implement a machanism like a "auto-register-plugin"

Comment: Unless you're trying to put this in a static library, you shouldn't need to reference the source file from code. (You still need to make sure your IDE actually compiles and links the file, but that should happen automatically like with any other file)

Comment: yes , these code are in a static lib...

Answer (score 0):

You must compile this file and link output together with your other object files. This is the only way adding the variable defined in it to your application.

Comment: can I link some object files use link flags explicitly? if yes, which flags can be used in xcode/gcc?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a library is that the modules therein are included only if necessary. The canonical way of indicating that a module is necessary is to ODR-use some name defined in the module.

If you want to unconditionally link modules into an executable, you can do so (on most build systems) by simply adding the filenames of the compiled modules to the list of filenames to be linked into the final executable. That means modifying the build instructions every time you add a new module.

If you want to store modules in a library and still get it linked into the executable, you could add a small module to the executable which references some symbol in every module you wish to include. That requires modifying the reference module every time you add a new module.

If you really want to do this with the command line and you happen to be using a linker whose options are compatible with GNU `ld` and a compiler whose options are compatible with gcc/g++, you can do so as follows:

```
gcc -o MAIN MAIN.cc -Wl,-u,SYMBOL -lLIBRARY
```

Here, you can repeat the options as often as you want (aside from `-o MAIN`, of course). The linker option `-u SYMBOL` causes `SYMBOL` to be marked as undefined, which will cause the linker to include a module which defines it from the supplied libraries. Because it is not a common linker option and the linker is being invoked implicitly by `gcc`, we need to use the gcc-specific `-Wl,option,option,...` syntax which adds each option in the comma separated list to the linker command.

This solution also requires the build instructions to be modified every time that a module is added, and in a more complex form than just adding the name of the module object file to a list of object files to be included.

Since all three solutions require some form of index of provided modules, you will probably want to be able to build the index -- in whatever form is dictated by the solution -- through a build rule. That might affect your preferences for the solution.

---

Full example as a proof-of-concept:

#### File: regmain.cc

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Starting " << argv[0] << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

#### File: register.cc

```
#include <iostream>
class Register {
  public:
    Register() {
      std::cout << "Registered\n";
    }
};

Register registry;
```

#### Build and run:

```
$ g++ -c -o regmain.o regmain.cc
$ g++ -c -o register.o register.cc
$ ar rcs libregister.a register.o
$ g++ -o regmain regmain.o -Wl,-u,registry -L. -lregister
$ ./regmain
Registered
Starting ./regmain
```